# how to get JSON data from unusual port in php?

Tags: php, get, port

i have scout_realtime, and i want to get stats.json from it. in debug it looks like

```
91.205.168.39 - - [10/Nov/2018:09:54:22 CET] "GET /stats.json HTTP/1.1" 200 3896
http://188.165.3.*:5556/ -> /stats.json
```

how to get it manially? I tried to do something like this:

```
$status = file_get_contents('http://188.165.3.*:5556/stats.gson')
```

but it doesnt work

Comment: Welcome on SO. Just a note about a _reproducible_ example. As said in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, when you ask a question it is important to explain what doesn't work, what error you get, and to give a minimalist reproducible example that we can run on our machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://188.165.3.*:5556/stats.json';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

ok i made it myself :D

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities to fetch your datas.

Firstly you can use [cURL](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). CURL is really good to send requests. As you showed in your own answer you can send an HTTP request in only few lines. I won't show a CURL example because it's already done in your answer.
Please note that you can use libraries like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) to send requests, it's easier.

Then, I'm not sure about what doesn't work in your code, but it is possible to fetch datas on a given port using file_get_contents. Here is the little example tested with PHP 7.2.10.

*server.php*

```
<?php

echo 'Hi from server';
```

*client.php*

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://localhost:8080/server.php');
```

*server.php* acts as the server you are trying to hit. It's supposed to return a simple string.

*client.php* is the script that's trying to fetch the datas.

Then if you run `php -S localhost:8080 -t .` in the directory where *server.php* is, you can execute the client.

Please note that you can configure the behaviour of [file_get_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) by giving it a *context* parameter. See the [stream_context_create](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) documentation to learn more about it.

> This answer aims to show that it is possible to fetch datas using file_get_contents, but if you need some specific parameters to fetch your datas like configuring a proxy, a port or something more complexe that just read the file, I suggest to use an HTTP-dedicated function or library, like cURL or Guzzle.